# how to create custom labels that can be removed/added dynamically

Tags: flutter

I want to write `A cat` in the `textField2` and when I tap `add/remove` button, that text should be added as a custom label.

then when I tap on those `labels` the `word` will be written to the `textfield 1`. I'm hoping to use a `gesture detector` for this.

The custom labels should `rearrange/move` to the `next line` if the container `width is not enough`.
`Any ideas how to do it?` I think there is an official widget that we can use instead of the `label`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for the custom label part, use [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html):

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('AH')),
      label: const Text('Hamilton'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('ML')),
      label: const Text('Lafayette'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('HM')),
      label: const Text('Mulligan'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('JL')),
      label: const Text('Laurens'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Wrap** with different kind of **alignment** available :

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('AH')),
      label: const Text('Hamilton'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('ML')),
      label: const Text('Lafayette'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('HM')),
      label: const Text('Mulligan'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: const Text('JL')),
      label: const Text('Laurens'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Alignments:
[image]

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-wrap-widget-e1ee0b005b16
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/WrapAlignment-class.html